# Why does the water level go down when a dense object is moved from a boat to the bottom of the pool

Tags: classical-mechanics, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Imagine you have a container ship with an extremely heavy mass on it. Why does the water level on the ship drop when the mass is placed in water?

Comment: Because of Contact forces and the local gravitational field. Go read about Archimedes's Principle at a large number of sources: physics texts, Hyperphysics, Wikipedia. It's already on the web and in print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic buoyancy question: Man in a boat with a stone](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30268/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an excellent problem. It is counter intuitive, so the following drawing might help:

[image]

Assuming the volume of the sphere is small, it will not displace a lot of water when at the bottom of the pool. However, if it's placed on top of the boat, the boat will now have to displace enough water to support the extra weight of the lead sphere. The volume of water displaced when lead sphere is on the boat is: Volume_water displaced=Weight of boat/rho_water*g

This quality is much larger then the volume of the sphere if the density of the lead sphere is much larger than the density of water.